# Avoid storing objects in Jupyter notebook cache

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Jupyter kindly stores my objects in output variables like `_1`, `_2`, ... `_10`.  Often in the course of working within a notebook I overwrite my old results with new ones and overwrite my old cells with new ones.

However my data continues to stay in memory, living in these hidden output variables.  Is there a way to disable this behavior either on the user's side "please don't store any output variables in my notebooks" or on the object's side "please don't store me in output variables"?

Answer (score 2):

Output variables are created only when the last sentence in a cell is an expression with a value different than `None` and does not have a semicolon at the end. Thus you have full control at the cell level: Use a semicolon to disable both displaying and creation of output variable. Use `print` or`display` (both return `None`) to get a visual representation of the object without creating the output variable.

The following examples are from the IPython console but the notebook works the same.

```
In [1]: 'hello'
Out[1]: hello

In [2]: 'hello';

In [3]: print('hello')
hello

In [4]: display('hello')
'hello'
```

At this point `_1` has been defined and bound to `'hello'` but `_2`, `_3` and `_4` are undefined.